# Extracting HTML code

Tags: html, fireworks

Ive built an interactive map on Fireworks that I want to upload to my site. However, I'm strugling to extract the HTML.

I was wondering how you get the HTML code from a firework HTML file. I've tried the 'inspect element' and copying the HTML but it doesnt come out right. Is there an easier way?

Comment: don't do this.. trust me.. you don't want fireworks to generate code for you. it will be impossible to update, work only in a small areas of browsers / devices and cause a huge headache. use this program to design only. or create animated gifs.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Do you know of any adobe or any other software that would be more approriate to design HTML/Javascript interactive maps?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use JavaScript to get all the HTML from the page: `document.innerHTML`

Hope this can point you in the right direction.